# Excel Solver Ignoring Constraint in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, constraints, solver

I am trying to find a maximum return for a simple portfolio using Solver. Using Solver in the worksheet directly works sensibly, however it does not when the commands are set in VBA. Instead (as you can see from the screengrab)it ignores one of the constraints (that the sum of weights calculated in T10 should =1). Interestingly it works fine if I change the third line to say:

```
SolverAdd CellRef:="$T$10", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="100"
```

Or any other integer other than "1".
  (It may also be ignoring the other constraint but I cannot check this).
The table looks like this:
[image]

And my code is:

```
Sub FindRange()

                SolverReset
                SolverOk SetCell:="$T$7", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$O$10:$R$10"
                SolverAdd CellRef:="$T$10", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
                SolverAdd CellRef:="$O$10:$R$10", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
                SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
                SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
                Range("T9").Value = Range("T7").Value
           End Sub
```

Any suggestions gratefully welcomed!

Comment: The code looks good to me.  Does it seem to iterate the same way non-VBA vs VBA?  Maybe try adding the `CellRef`'s before the `SolverOK`?

Comment: Maybe try using just `FormulaText:=1`? (without the double quotes)  I mention it because the [code on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838657.aspx) doesn't use quotes.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the double quotes does help (i.e. it stays below 10), however it now ignores "$O$10:$R$10" should equal 0. So both constraints are being ignored

Comment: It appears to work non-VBA

Comment: Rebooting Excel seems to have solved it....

Comment: ... But the problem returns.

Comment: I am duplicating the same error in VBA for Office 2003 and 2010 in that it ignores the FormulaText:="1" when it is 1 but is fine for any other value. Currently getting around it by using 0.99999.. but am exploring some work around

Answer (score 3):

Found a work around for the bug. For the flag "FormulaText:=1". instead of using 1, use a reference to any cell with the value 1 instead.

I.e., Change "FormulaText:=1" to "FormulaText:=$H$5" where $H$5's value is 1

Comment: Unfortunately this still fails sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a bug here whenever the value is exactly 1. Other postings state that the above solution (putting the value into a cell) is unreliable.
I have found it does not work a my code always refers to a cell which holds the constraint limit.
My (crude) solution is to shift the limit value by 1 part in 10^12 or lower in the appropriate direction which sort of makes the constraint into a < or > rather than a <= or >=.
So rather than:

SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("SolverParam").Address, Relation:=3, _
    FormulaText:=Range("SolverConstraint").value

Use:

SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("SolverParam").Address, Relation:=3, _
    FormulaText:=Range("SolverConstraint").value
 + Abs(Range("SolverConstraint").value) * 1e-12

And use the opposite sign for Relation:=1

In this trivial example SolverParam is a single cell parameter to be adjusted and SolverConstraint is a single cell lower bound.

This is the only consistent approach I can foresee to have a uniform handling of all values

On further looking I found another solution from the web

FormulaText:="=" & Range("SolverConstraint").value

Seems to work reliably

Comment: Changing `Relation:=2, FormulaText:1` to `Relation:=2, FormulaText:="=1"` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I solved it in the following way:
Just type FormulaText:=1  without the quotes for 1.