# VBA Solver dislikes paying attention to constraints

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've been trying to make the solver in VBA work nicely on GRG non-linear problems with named ranges. It's going so-so - it keeps ignoring the binary constraint. Attempts to follow other posts with similar issues have failed.

```
Sub Solver()
'
' Solver Macro
' For solving once we have the data
'

    SolverReset
       'Clearing out the old solver data, allows for named ranges to be used

    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("VariableRange"), Relation:=1, FormulaText:=Range("One")
    ' Previous advice has been to used a range that ='s 1, as that can sometimes make things work. Part A
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("VariableRange"), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    'Part B
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("VariableRange"), Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
    'Parts A and B along with this part are supposed to mimic the binary setting, in an attempt to get things working.

    SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$1", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$D$2"
    'D2 is my limit that D1 needs to stay inside of.
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$1", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="-$D$2"
    'Could probably include an ABS on D1 to reduce VBA-ness. Either way, needs to fall within D2

    SolverOk SetCell:="$A$1", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range("VariableRange"), _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        'And now we TRY to solve

        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
        'I don't want to have to confirm to keep the results
        SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
        'And I'd like to keep the results!

End Sub
```

My research has had me stumble upon [Excel Solver Ignoring Constraint in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620177/excel-solver-ignoring-constraint-in-vba) along with other threads. I've tried every combination present in that thread, and I've gotten nowhere.

Worth noting: I've also tried a manual approach to forcing binary - sumproduct(range)=sum(range) must be true - but that just generates everything as 0, which is useless.

Comment: Is `$D$1` an element of `VariableRange`? If it isn't, I don't see how `$D$1` is part of the Solver solution space. If it is, then the constraints are potentially in conflict. Your code works (maximum found within constraints) in my hands for a simple example.

Comment: $D$1 = sumproduct(Column I'm messing with * Variable Range) where variable range is an offset of the column I'm messing with. Basically, I have a column of numbers. I need to find which, if any, combination of numbers net out. So -20, 20, 100, and 300 should give me back -20 and 20 as the combination. However, if I have -20, -40, -50, 100, and 40, I'd like -20, -40, -50, and 100 returned as the solution instead of -40 and 40, since that clears more numbers out. 

Strangely, evolutionary works with the constraints. But if I change to GRG Nonlinear, it breaks horribly.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by executing the solver twice rather than once:

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$A$1", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range("VariableRange"), _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    'And now we TRY to solve

    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    'I don't want to have to confirm to keep the results
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    'This second iterations solves it correctly
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    'And I'd like to keep the results!
```